# How can I debug an Android style inheritance issue?

Tags: android

When doing web development, you can inspect an element and see which classes provide which css rules. Is there an equivalent for Android development?

TLDR; Here's an example of a style inheritance problem that I had and solved:

I had a dialog has the Holo theme, but the text color was dark, even when I tried to set the text color to white.

This is the dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              style="@style/Theme.Dialog"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the `style.xml` resource:

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

It turned out that I was using a `Fragment` whose `Activity` was a `ListActivity`, and it defined getView, which created the view from an xml style that set the text color to be dark. It would have liked to see what was setting the text color.

Comment: Why are you applying a dialog theme to a `ListView`? Is it supposed to look like a dialog?

Comment: Yes, what's strange is that when I select an element of the list view, it's yet another instance of the same dialog class, and yet the Holo style shows up properly on that dialog box.

Comment: I'm not aware of tools for inspecting view styles at runtime, but you shouldn't apply a dialog theme to a Listview. Dialog is styleable via the constructor and DialogFragment via the setStyle() method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments on your question, but for future, if you want to get an idea of the view hierarchy (not styles) for your app - you can do so in Eclipse.

Run the app.
Window > Open Perspective > DDMS.
In the DDMS pane, click the icon to the left that looks like a stack of phones (next to the camera icon)

You can mouse around the screen and get a visual representation of the view hierarchy.

Might help in some way.